# $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

I am new to Hadoop/hive.i have install hadoop and hive.it work fine when i am using hive as command prompt but which i am going to implement JDBC of hive then type the following command

```
hive>$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver
```

Then get following error so pls Help me how to implement jdbc of hive Pls anyone Help me...

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver
Starting Hive Thrift Server
WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated. Please use org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the log4j.properties files.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:93)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.<init>(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer.main(HiveServer.java:674)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be because there's another process (maybe another hiveserver) already listening on port 10000. Issue `netstat -ntulp | grep ':10000'` to see it that is the case and kill the process listed there or start Thrift server on another port, e.g:

`hive --service hiveserver -p 10001`

Comment: Thanks for reply dear but now it will get this problem                     Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:353)
 at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:215)
 at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:27)
 at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:206)

Comment: Yo may try to increase the heap size (set it in `hive-env.sh`). However, I'd suggest you to create a new question including your code snippet which accesses to Hive